How can I appeal the deletion of questions? A question was falsely flagged as "spam or offensive," but it was just about school classes
This question got deleted as "offensive or spam": "BUD" (for Android OS) has asset editors, map editors... how to use wireless mouses with this? As "Godot-4" does selects/drags/rotations with mouses? ["BUD" (for Android OS) has asset editors, map editors... how to use wireless mouses with this? As "Godot-4" does selects/drags/rotations with mouses?]
I can accept that most YouTube videos cause harm and that I therefore should not link to YouTube,
but this video was just of wireless mouses + asset editor interfaces,
and the motive was just to produce open source school classes.
I would remove the links, because I do not want to support a website which spreads as much harm as YouTube does.
But I do not agree that this is "spam or offensive," so I wish to appeal the deletion and ask someone in the position to review the question as to if it should count as offensive or spam. If it is not offensive or spam, wish the deletion revoked and to restore reputation from this.

Given that spammers will link to YouTube videos in order to promote them, if you have posted a YouTube video to support your question, it would be wise to say that it's your video in the post. Simply say something like "I uploaded this video to demonstrate the behavior on my system" so that it's clear that the video supports your question instead of the other way around.

TLDR: You ask on the per site meta - but I've taken a look and resolved it.
Its not a problem with youtube, though admittedly we get a lot of people who try to use our site to promote their own site. I'm going to clear the flag flags but it is not a good fit for us, and I'll be closing the post.
There's two issues here, android (as on a phone) is off topic for us. Secondly - while we try our best to 'fix' posts, the post heavily relies on the youtube videos linked, and that and other posts by OP seem rather difficult to read/understand. As it is it feels more like a feature request to BUD rather than an actual question.
Also, this might have been a better fit for the super user meta, even if the end result would have been the same. While we do have super user moderators active here, this wouldn't be true for all sites.
(Quick note - I'm writing from the point of view as a moderator on super user. We and Us would refer to the site mostly, and any actions taken by me would be in first person. The actions/issues are primarily on super user)
